# some clients takes very long to start RDS session

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, login, rds

I've hit a wall on this one.

I have a 2012R2 RDS setup, it's not struggling with resources, config is good.
When users login, some complain that it takes very long to connect (start session).
I've tested with a test account from multiple clients and the results are:
Client1 - Session start takes 30 - 40 seconds - Windows 10
Client2 - Session start takes 17 - 20 seconds - Windows 10
Client3 - Session start takes 7 - 10 seconds - Windows 10
Client4 - Session start takes 30 - 50 seconds - Windows 7
Client5 - Session start takes 7 - 10 seconds - Windows 7
Non of the above clients are in the same domain or network as the RDS, DNS is setup properly.

I've ruled out the RDS itself as connections are all external from otherwise good connections and computers that run well.

Any ideas on how to optimize the client for the RDS connections?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying mstsc.exe, mstscxa.dll, mstsc.exe.mui, mstscxa.dll.mui from one of the machines with faster session start time to one of the slowest machines just as a last resort, this actually made the session start time go from about 37 seconds to 9 seconds. The behaviour is persistent when changing back and fort.